# How to import a third party library "causalImpact" using R script in AzureML studio?

Tags: r, github, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I tried to import causalImpact library from github using "devtools" in AzureML studio for one of my projects.
code used was:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact")
```

Unfortunately, Azure doesn't support this.So tried importing it following the procedure in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/).It is giving multiple errors on the name of dependent packages of casualImpact(i.e. BOOM, BH etc.). Can anyone help me out in importing this package on Azure?

This is the R-script I used following the link given above:

```
library(assertthat)
library(dplyr)
library(hflights)
library(Lahman)
library(magrittr)
library(LGPL)
install.packages("src/BH_1.55.0-3.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
success <- library("BH ", lib.loc=".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose=TRUE)

library(BH)
install.packages("src/Boom_0.1.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
success <- library("Boom ", lib.loc=".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose=TRUE)

install.packages("src/BoomSpikeSlab.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
success <- library("BoomSpikeSlab", lib.loc=".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose=TRUE)

install.packages("src/bsts_0.5.1.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
success <- library("bsts", lib.loc=".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
install.packages("src/CausalImpact.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
success <- library("CausalImpact", lib.loc=".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to upload all dependent packages of casualImpact as a zip file - see sample [here](http://gallery.azureml.net/Details/7507f907deb845d9b9b193b455a8615d) which shows uploading two packages required for xgboost

Comment: I had tried that too. This is the R script I was trying just to install:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of zipping downloaded binary packages of dependent libraries as shown [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/),dependent library folders from "C:\Users\\Documents\R\win-library\3.0\" should be binded as Zip folder. This will work with the same procedure given in the blog(mentioned in the question)